# How to sum prometheus counters when k8s pods restart

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus

I'm running Prometheus in a kubernetes cluster. All is running find and my UI pods are counting visitors.

[image]

Please ignore the title, what you see here is the query at the bottom of the image. It's a counter. The gaps in the graph are due to pods restarting. I have two pods running simultaneously!

Now suppose I would like to count the total of visitors, so I need to sum over all the pods

[image]

This is what I expect considering the first image, right?

However, I don't want the graph to drop when a pod restarts. I would like to have something cumulative over a specified amount of time (somehow ignoring pods restarting). Hope this makes any sense. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Below is suggested to do the following

[image]

Its a bit hard to see because I've plotted everything there, but the suggested answer `sum(rate(NumberOfVisitors[1h])) * 3600` is the continues green line there. What I don't understand now is the value of 3 it has? Also why does the value increase after 21:55, because I can see some values before that.

As the approach seems to be ok, I noticed that the actual increase is actually 3, going from 1 to 4. In the graph below I've used just one time series to reduce noise

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rate, then sum, then multiply by the time range in seconds. That will handle rollovers on counters too.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `sum(rate(NumberOfVisitors[1h]))  * 3600`? For some reason that graph will reach a value of 3, which I don't understand (I'll add the graph to my post!)

Comment: You would usually want to use a much smaller range, probably 1m or similar. This would be averaging the rate over a whole hour which will probably underestimate as you noted.

Comment: I think 3 is correct, its an increase from 1 to 4 :) Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus doesn't provide the ability to sum counters, which may be reset. Additionally, the [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function in Prometheus has some issues, which may prevent from using it for querying [counter](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter) increase over the specified time range:

- It may return fractional values over integer counters because of extrapolation. See [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746) for details.
- It may miss counter increase between raw sample just before the lookbehind window in square brackets and the first raw sample inside the lookbehind window. For example, `increase(NumberOfVisitors[1m])` at timestamp `t` may miss the counter increase between the last raw sample just before the `t-1m` time and the first raw sample at `(t-1m ... t]` time range. See more details [here](https://medium.com/@romanhavronenko/victoriametrics-promql-compliance-d4318203f51e) and [here](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/1215#issuecomment-850305711).
- It may miss the increase for the first raw sample in a time series. For example, if the `NumberOfVisitors` counter is increased to 10 just before the first scrape of this counter by Prometheus, then `increase()` over the time range with the first sample would under-count the counter increase by 10.

Prometheus developers are going to fix these issues - see [this design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y2Mp041_2v0blnKnZk7keCnJZICeK2YWUQuXH_m4DVc/edit). In the mean time it is possible to use [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) - its' `increase()` function is free from these issues.

Returning to the original question - the sum of multiple counters, which may be reset, can be returned with the following [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) query in VictoriaMetrics:

```
running_sum(sum(increase(NumberOfVisitor)))
```

It uses the following functions:

- [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) for calculating increase per each counter between adjacent points on the graph.
- [sum()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum) for summing the calculated increases per each point on the graph.
- [running_sum()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#running_sum) for calculating the running sum over per-point increases on the graph.