# Calculate sum of the Prometheus counter's values even if application restarted

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

As you know, Prometheus counters reset after application restarts. Is there any way to calculate the sum of the counter's values in Grafana somehow even after restarts?
Found old question [How to sum prometheus counters when k8s pods restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58069711/how-to-sum-prometheus-counters-when-k8s-pods-restart)
but might be something new introduced since 2019.
[image]

Comment: Two things: 1. you highlighted not all resets. There were to resets at 07.12 at around midnight and afternoon. 2. function `increase` automatically adjusts for resets, so something like `increase(metric [30d])` will produce what you want.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed increase(metric [30d]) good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for any trickery: function `increase` [deals with resets automatically](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase):

> Breaks in monotonicity (such as counter resets due to target restarts) are automatically adjusted for.

So query like `increase(metric [30d])` will calculate total change in the counter value over last 30 days.

---

Also notice, that results of `increase` might differ slightly from manually calculated, as there is some extrapolation involved:

> The increase is extrapolated to cover the full time range as specified in the range vector selector, so that it is possible to get a non-integer result even if a counter increases only by integer increments.